# How do I get the following to be in numerical form?

Tags: numerics

How to get this to be a numerical result
[image]

Here is sample code that produces the same kind of problem; the 10^3 in the square root does not get simplified

```
mass=2.325x10^-26 kg; 
kb=1.38x10^-23 kg m^2/sec^2/kelvin;
temp=5000 kelvin; 
velocity=Sqrt[3 kb temp/mass];

Assuming[m>0&&sec>0,Simplify[velocity]]
```

Comment: Did you try typing this into Mathematica?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please add Mathematica code to your post that you have tried out so far in a copy-paste-able format. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this `94.3569 Sqrt[(m^2 10^3)/sec^2]/.{m->1,sec->1}` which returns 2983.83 or this `Assuming[m>0&&sec>0,Simplify[94.3569 Sqrt[(m^2 10^3)/sec^2]]]` which returns 2983.83 m/sec

Comment: You have written `kb=1.38x10^-23`. I assume that you wanted to multiply, right? You should have written `mass = 2.325 10^-26 kg;` and likewise `kb = 1.38 10^-23 kg m^2/sec^2/kelvin;` Then it works fine; see [`this`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3Dr8.png)

Comment: bmf-your idea resolves the numeric issue but the units don't simplify. I can live with that so THANX

Comment: @EdFriedman what do you mean the units do not simplify? First of all, you have written the units by hand and have not used the command [`Quantity`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quantity.html) --- see the docs from the link. And in addition to that, in the screenshot I just see `m/sec`. What were you expecting for the velocity?

Answer (score 1):

Benefitting from all the comments above:

```
$Version
```

> "12.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)"

```
mass = Quantity[2.325*^-26, "Kilograms"]
kb = Quantity[1, "BoltzmannConstant"]
temp = Quantity[5000, "Kelvins"]
velocity = UnitSimplify[
     Sqrt[(3*kb*temp)/mass]]
```

[image]